# friend C++ изменение значения переменной класса

Tags: c++, классы, friend

Разбираюсь в том, как работает `friend` в c++.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что `friend` используется для изменения объектов класса, в том числе и `private`. В таком случае в реальных условиях `friend` используется для тестирования корректной работы классов? Какие еще типичные юзкейсы могут сопровождаться данной конструкцией?

Какая реализация `test_friend_func` может привести к изменению `test_vector` в примере ниже?

```
#include <vector>

class test_class{
    friend void test_friend_func();
    std::vector<int> test_vector;
public:
    test_class(){}
    void foo(){
        //...
    }
};
```

Comment: Ну я бы не говорил так — "для изменения"... Для доступа. Примеры? Например, описываем оператор вывода `ostream&<<` — или надо выводить только то, что доступно по открытому интерфейсу, или сделать этот оператор другом и просто обращаться к чему угодно. Как и в обычной жизни, дружба — занятие достаточно опасное, если друг готов навредить... :)

Comment: @Harry, благодарю! Не могли бы оформить ответ? Я приму и закроем вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну я бы не говорил так — "для изменения"... Для доступа.

Примеры? Например, описываем оператор вывода `ostream&<<` — или надо выводить только то, что доступно по открытому интерфейсу, или можно сделать этот оператор другом и просто обращаться к чему угодно.

Но, как и в обычной жизни, дружба — занятие достаточно опасное, если друг готов навредить... :)